# Android: Pop-up alert while calculations are performed

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I'm moving a pc java code to android by using Android Studio. The java code performs some numeric calculations routines and in a basic computer it can take few seconds to return the problem solution. The java code works very pretty.

By clicking in a button, the routine starts. I'd like to know how to show an elegant "alert" mensagem while the calculations are performed. A kind of "please wait" in a pop-up.

My basic code:

```
static double h,w,l,t,Te;    
static int ambiente;
private EditText numeroin;
//private TextView numeroout;

public void cliqueBotao(View view){

Intent intent = getIntent();
ambiente = intent.getIntExtra("ambiente_selec", 0);

numeroin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_h);
h= Double.parseDouble(numeroin.getText().toString());

numeroin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_w);
w= Double.parseDouble(numeroin.getText().toString());

numeroin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_l);
l= Double.parseDouble(numeroin.getText().toString());

numeroin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_t);
t= Double.parseDouble(numeroin.getText().toString());

numeroin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_T);
Te= Double.parseDouble(numeroin.getText().toString());

(HERE STARTS THE NUMERICAL CALCULATIONS CODE)

/**AlertDialog msg;
msg=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
msg.setMessage("Calculando");
msg.show();*/

}
```

By the way, in the button xml code the OnClick option is seted to "cliqueBotao".

Answer (score 0):

You should do that math in a worker thread, take a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can use onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute callbacks to control your pop-up dialog lifecycle and even display current calculation progress.

Comment: I didn't know the AsyncTask class. I'm a "black screen and white characters" programer. I'll study your suggestion. Tks!

Comment: Any big and slow work like complex calculus should be done outside the main UI thread, this is where AsyncTask comes in hand. If you're able to achieve what you need with this API suggestion, please accept my answer! Regards.

Comment: Nice! But it was really a battle to discover how to start the new activity in AsyncTask class. The best answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332930/android-asynctask-start-new-activity-in-onpostexecute

Comment: @LuisFernandoMoura you never mentioned you needed to start a new activity after work was finished. If you did, I would have exemplified for you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Rogério, AsyncTask was the best solution to my problem. On the other hand, I had to discover how to start a new activity by using AsyncTask. It was not easy for me, but a useful solution is here: [Android AsyncTask: start new Activity in onPostExecute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332930/android-asynctask-start-new-activity-in-onpostexecute)